# Can't `stopPropagation()` because of events bubbling order?

Tags: angular, angular6

I have registered event handlers on `tr` and on `input` inside it - code below. Clicking on row works ok, but clicking on checkbox makes call `rowClick()` **before** `onChange()`, so i think that `stopPropagation()` and `preventDefault()` can't do what i expected. How to solve this ? I'm using Angular6.

```
onChange($event:any) {
    $event.preventDefault();
    $event.stopPropagation();
}

<tr (click)="rowClick()">
  <td><input type="checkbox" (change)="onChange($event)"/></td>
</tr>
```

**EDIT**
Plunker [here](https://next.plnkr.co/edit/m4cOSbgdm8Uq7SB5)

Comment: try `(click)="$event.stopPropagation()"` on _input_

Comment: You're right. Thats works, too. Thank You ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically you're trying to prevent on `change` event of your input, but the thing is `click` event is bubbling up to parent `tr` element. That's why you should stop the `click` event on that `td`.

Better way would be encapsulate this DOM behaviour inside directive and use it in declarative manner whenever you need it.

**Directive**

```
import {
  Directive, HostListener
} from "@angular/core";

@Directive({
    selector: "[stop-click-propagation]"
})
export class StopClickPropagation
{
    @HostListener("click", ["$event"])
    public onClick(event: any): void
    {
        event.stopPropagation();
    }
}
```

**Html**

```
<tr (click)="rowClick()">
  <td>
    <input stop-click-propagation type="checkbox" (change)="onChange($event)"/>
  </td>
</tr>
```

> **Note:** Make sure you register `StopClickPropagation` inside `NgModule` to make it work.